# Socket programming in C not working on two distinct PCs

Tags: c, sockets

I have written a **simple socket programming application in C**.This code is working on the loopback address. Also this program works well if the two computers(one server one client) are in same network(I tried it on a college LAN network) But when I tried to run the same  code on two completely different computers(**In two different networks**)Then it displays error in  "connect" method of client.Client is unable to connect to server.Please help me out guys.I tried almost everything but nothing helped so please help me.Please help me ASAP I am struck on this assignment for almost a month now.
Thanks in advanced!

here is the code:
for Client.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int chat();
int main(){
chat();
}

int chat()
{

  int clientid, n = 0;
  char msgsend[512], msgrecv[512];
  struct sockaddr_in client; 


  memset(msgrecv, '0', sizeof(msgrecv));

  clientid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(clientid == -1){
    printf("Could not create a socket!\n");
    return -1;
  }

  client.sin_family = AF_INET;
  client.sin_addr.s_addr = /*INADDR_ANY;*/inet_addr("10.200.56.187");
  client.sin_port = htons(5001);


  printf(" Trying to connect...");

  if(connect(clientid, (struct sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client)) < 0){
    printf("Error:Connection failed\n");
    return -1;
  }
  printf("Connected");
  while(1){
    printf("please enter your reply\n");
    gets(msgsend);

    send(clientid, msgsend, sizeof(msgsend) - 1, 0);
    n = recv(clientid, msgrecv, sizeof(msgrecv) - 1, 0);

    if(n < 0){
      printf("Read error\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("server says:");
    msgrecv[n] = 0;
    fputs(msgrecv, stdout);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}



And here is the code:
for server.c


    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include<fcntl.h>

    int chat();
    int main(){
      chat();
      }
    int chat(){

      int serverid, clientid, n = 0, len;
      char msgsend[512], msgrecv[512];
      struct sockaddr_in server,client;

      serverid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

      memset(&server, '0', sizeof(server));
      memset(msgrecv, '0', sizeof(msgrecv));

      server.sin_family = AF_INET;
      server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
      server.sin_port = htons(5001);

      bind(serverid, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));

      if( listen(serverid, 10) == -1){
        printf("ERROR");
        return -1;
      }
      len = sizeof(client);
        clientid = accept(serverid, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &len);
      while(1){



        n =  recv(clientid, msgrecv, sizeof(msgrecv) - 1, 0);
        if(n < 0){
          printf("Error while reading...\n");
          return -1;
        }

        printf("client says:");
        msgrecv[n] = 0;
        fputs(msgrecv, stdout);
        printf("\n");
        printf("enter your reply\n");
        gets(msgsend);
        send(clientid, msgsend, sizeof(msgsend) - 1, 0);
        printf("\n");
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Probably not code related. Can you successfully PING the address you are trying to connect to?

Comment: A firewall in the way? No routing between the two networks?

Comment: Actually the ip mentioned is a Personal PC of my friend so I didn't try pinging it! should I try it?

Comment: your memset code is also wrong - surely you meant to `memset` with `0` or `'\0'` instead of `'0'`

Comment: and yes, you should try to ping

Comment: I tried pinging but it returns nothing..and yes memset code is wrong but then it should have created the problem at the time of loopback address only..isn't it??And I am working on ubuntu (both server and client) so firewall is not my problem right??)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [private IP](http://whatismyipaddress.com/private-ip) for server address. Private IPs cannot be addressed from outside local/private network.

Comment: Thanks nishant! This means I will have to buy a static ip for this program to work :p By the way Is there any other way for this problem?

Comment: @user2334787 : Well I do not know the exact solution for this, you can try searching on Internet, or wait for others to answer.

Comment: people commonly use things like dyndns to register names to short-lived IP addresses.  They change almost immediately when your IP changes and you can put a client on the computer to update it automatically.  There are/were free ones out there, just look around.

Comment: Thank a lot guys! I will try to find out the solution as suggested by nishant and xaxxon ..Anyway Now at least I am sure that this not a problem of my code! :)

Answer (score 0):

Private IP is one thing, the server you are trying to connect to should either be in your own network or should at least be dns resolvable.

Also when trying to connect to a server always try to get the IP associated to the server name by using calls like gethostbyname() etc this is because your server's IP might just change because of a DNS refesh but hostname almost all the time remains same.

Answer (score 0):

As others located you have to be aware of underlying network. You may not be able to communicate your app even you get a static ip. Possible reasons are:

- A firewall in any of host machines or any of routers/modems in the way.
- NAT configuration on routers in both networks

You have to use ping,traceroute,telnet (and possibly other network tools) to diagnose network issues.

You can use tcpdump for deeper analyses.